# submit the form after a specific time (When time is finished)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on an online exam website. 
In the exam page, there is a Countdown timer which is calculated by subtracting date and time (database datetime - current datetime).
So I need when the timer is over, the page automatically submit itself.
is it possible? I think I should combine Javascript and php somehow but I have no idea how to do.
It also refresh itself automatically every one second to show the realtime timer.

```
$date_time=mysqli_query($server,"select * from exams where id='".$exam_page_id."'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($date_time)){
$ts1 = strtotime($datetime);
$ts2 = strtotime($row[6]); //datetime which is stored in database
$seconds_diff = $ts2 - $ts1;

echo '<span class="bg-danger">
Countdown timer: '.gmdate('H:i:s', $seconds_diff).'</span>';
```

Comment: Yes its possible. Yes you will need to do it in javascript. So you need to look for javascript tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto submit form after 5 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888166/auto-submit-form-after-5-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible . For that you need to write **setTimeout** function and inside that function you can make **AJAX** call to submit form after specific time interval.
Like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({
       url:'action.php',
       method:'POST',
       data:{'name':"xyz"},/*--Your data--*/
       success:function(res){
        alert(res);
       }
      })
   },1000);/*---(1000 = 1 second) Here you can set you time interval what ever you want--*/
});
```